# How to use row index and cell value in function applied to dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

I have a table similar to this, with the blank spaces being empty strings and the numbers being floats:

```
   1   2   3   4   5   6
A  
B                  8   5
C      5       7
D  2   3   5
E  0
```

I want to replace the value of each cell with the output of a function which takes two arguments: the index of the row and the value of the cell.

For example, the values in the first column should be replaced with the output of func(D, 2) and func(E, 0) and the empty cells should stay empty. The function output is a string.

Expected output table:

if func(D, 2) returns X and func(E, 0) returns Y, then column 1 should look like:

```
   1   2   3   4   5   6
A  
B                  8   5
C      5       7
D  X   3   5
E  Y
```

How do I do this?

Comment: try stack + reset_index

Comment: Can you create the expected output table? The way you've described what you expect is vague, e.g. do you want all the values of column 1 (i.e. A,B,C D,E) to be the result of those functions `func(D,2)` and `func(E,0)` combined? or do you want Row D, Column 1 to be the output of func(D,2)?

Comment: reflecting linamnt, adding an expected output table would help us formulate an answer

Comment: Apologies -- just added the output table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I would fill the dataframe:

```
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

then let's assume that your function is called `func` and it's first argument is row index, you can apply it using the `map` method while iterating over rows:

```
for idx in df.index:
   df.loc[idx] = df.loc[idx].map(lambda x: func(idx, x))
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error when trying this: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'. Appreciate the help though, will keep working on it

Comment: @rnkv2 I have no issue running it with the replicated dataframe I create. In particular `df.loc[idx]` is not a pandas DataFrame, but a pandas Series, which has a `map` attribute.

Comment: Found the issue -- I mistakenly duplicated a row index. Thanks a ton for the help!